# Getting null value after save conditions rule in magento 2.2.x

Tags: magento2.2

How to get serializes product condition value in magento 2.2.x.?

```
Array
(
    [rule_id] => 3
    [title] => sdsds
    [description] => sdsdsd
    [range] => 0
    [making_from] => 5
    [making_to] => 0
    [status] => 1
    [conditions_serialized] => {"type":"Magento\\CatalogRule\\Model\\Rule\\Condition\\Combine","attribute":null,"operator":null,"value":true,"is_value_processed":null,"aggregator":"all"}
    [actions_serialized] => {"type":"Magento\\CatalogRule\\Model\\Rule\\Action\\Collection","attribute":null,"operator":"=","value":null}
    [customer_group_ids] => Array
        (
        )

    [website_ids] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

Comment: Did you fix the issue?